# How to show an svg icon using svg image path in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to show SVG icons but the thing I couldn't find the way to show. I tried to use Image and Use components of react-native-svg but they don't work with that. And I tried to do that with native way but it's really hard work to show just SVG icons.

Example code:

```
<Svg width="80" height="80">
 <Image href={require('./svg/1f604.svg')} />
</Svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially, I had the same problem when I had SVG icons in my machine or saved in web URL.

I explored the [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) library, but it does not allow you to include source of SVG icon already created. We can only create new icons using that library.

Later I found [react-native-svg-uri](https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri) which does allow us to use a given path to the icon.

You can use it like this:

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';

<SvgUri
    width="200"
    height="200"
    source={{uri:'http://thenewcode.com/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg'}}
/>
```